# How can I decode date string to Date object from JSON?

Tags: json, swift, xcode

How can I decode timestamp to Date from JSON?

I get my date from the server as Json like this:

```
{

        "date": "2610-02-16T03:16:15.143Z"

    }
```

and im trying to build a Date class from it:

```
class Message : Decodable {

  var date: Date

}
```

its not working as Expected I am getting this error:

```
Failed to fetch messages: typeMismatch(Swift.Double, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "date", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Double but found a string/data instead.", underlyingError: nil))
```

Answer (score 0):

When decoding date info like this, you need to use a custom `dateDecodingStrategy`, and set the date parser's timezone and locale:

```
let data = """
{
    "date": "2610-02-16T03:16:15.143Z"
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

struct Message: Codable {
    let date: Date
}

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "GMT")
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(formatter)

do {
  let message = try decoder.decode(Message.self, from: data)
  print(message.date)
} catch {
  print(erroor)
}
```